# Filtering json response in Vue

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am having trouble with filtering a json response in Vue.

```js
return this.offers.filter(type => type.offers == 'Junior');
```

Whenever I leave it as `return this.offers`, in my html this is being displayed:

```html
{"-MN5agCddYAdy7c8GSSz": { "companyName": "dawdwad", "image": "da", "jobDescription": "dada", "location": "daw", "salary": "dadaw", "skill": "dawda", "tags": "dada", "title": "dwa" }, "-MN7vsTsNohgQigd3S26": { "companyName": "ejadfjaq", "image": "", "jobDescription": "dada", "location": "2sjawdja", "salary": "40324032", "skill": "Junior", "tags": "ux", "title": "fawd" } }
```

But I want only the fields with `"skill": "Junior"` to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is an object but `filter` only works on arrays.  You can use the [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop in a computed to reformat it and filter it the way you like:

```js
computed: {
  filteredOffers() {
    const filteredOffers = [];
    for(const key in this.offers) {
      if (this.offers[key].skill == 'Junior') filteredOffers.push(this.offers[key]);
    }
    return filteredOffers;
  }
}
```

This returns an array of the objects you want.  If you just want to display them raw in your template:

```html
<div id="app">
   {{ filteredOffers }}
</div>
```

Here's a demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      offers: {
        "-MN5agCddYAdy7c8GSSz": {
          "companyName":"dawdwad",
          "image":"da",
          "jobDescription":"dada",
          "location":"daw",
          "salary":"dadaw",
          "skill":"dawda",
          "tags":"dada",
          "title":"dwa"
        },
        "-MN7vsTsNohgQigd3S26":{
          "companyName":"ejadfjaq",
          "image":"",
          "jobDescription":"dada",
          "location":"2sjawdja",
          "salary":"40324032",
          "skill":"Junior",
          "tags":"ux",
          "title":"fawd"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredOffers() {
      const filteredOffers = [];
      for(const key in this.offers) {
        if (this.offers[key].skill == 'Junior') filteredOffers.push(this.offers[key]);
      }
      return filteredOffers;
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   {{ filteredOffers }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Got one more question. If I have one component with dropdown buttons, and in another component I fetch data and display it. How can I filter the data through component where I have only dropdown button?

Comment: You're welcome.  There are a few ways to share data among components.  If the components are not related in a simple parent/child relationship, [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/) is the best solution.